# PHP form tag difficulty

Tags: php

I would like to produce an application form, written in PHP and CSS, and my problem is this: In the  tag, I set up a submit button, and upon writing my name into the text bar, I get the sentence "The name that I have entered is: " at the TOP LEFT of my web page. I don't want this this sentence at the top of my page. I want this sentence BELOW the text box into which I enter my name. Having the sentence appear at the top of my web page means a badly designed web pae, but I don't know how to make this sentence appear where I want it to appear. OK, when I get rid of all the other codes (ie CSS codes etc) in my program and just have the  tag all by itself (together with the sentence "The name that I have entered is: "), I enter the name Gavin, and what I get is "The name that I have entered is: Gavin", and this sentence appears ABOVE the textbox. It seems that the position is default, and there is nothing that can be done. Am I right? Is there ANY way to reposition my sentence so it appears BELOW the text box. Also, is there any way to make my textbox disappear once I have entered my name and clicked on SUBMIT?

```
<?php
//brownuniversity.php
if (!empty($_POST['name'])) {
    echo "Hello, {$_POST["name"]}, and welcome.";
}
?>

<html>
<head>
  <title>Image</title>
<style>
p.pos_fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 30px;
  right: 50px;
  color: black;
}
h4 {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h4>Application Form</h4>
<img src="alphacentauri.jpg" alt="starcluster" width="200" height="200" /><br/><br/>
<p class="pos_fixed">
  <b>Brown University:</b>
  <br><br><br>
  <b>Department of Physics:</b>
</p>
<ul>
  <li>question1</li>
  <li>question2</li>
</ul>

The name that I have entered is:

<form action="brownuniversity.php" method="post">
  If you want to take part in this star-gazing project, enter your name:
  <input type="text"  name="name">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: First of all, please tidy your code and look at how to format it correctly. Secondly, move the echo underneath the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> at the TOP LEFT of my web page

Because that's where you're putting it.  Take a look:

```
...

if(!empty($_POST['name'])) {
    echo "Hello, {$_POST["name"]}, and welcome.";
}
echo <<<_END
<html>

...
```

You're outputting the sentence *before the HTML even begins*.  So of course it's going to be... before the HTML.

If you want it in a specific location of the page, output it at that location.  For example:

```
...

<?php
if(!empty($_POST['name'])) {
?>
    The name that I have entered is: <?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?>
<?php
}
?>

<form action="brownuniversity.php"  method="post">

...
```

Answer (score -1):

For a starter, tidy up the code.

This hopefully works.

```
<?php
//brownuniversity.php
if (!empty($_POST['name'])) {
    echo "Hello, {$_POST["name"]}, and welcome.";
}
?>

<html>
<head>
  <title>Image</title>
<style>
p.pos_fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 30px;
  right: 50px;
  color: black;
}
h4 {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h4>Application Form</h4>
<img src="alphacentauri.jpg" alt="starcluster" width="200" height="200" /><br/><br/>
<p class="pos_fixed">
  <b>Brown University:</b>
  <br><br><br>
  <b>Department of Physics:</b>
</p>
<ul>
  <li>question1</li>
  <li>question2</li>
</ul>

The name that I have entered is:
<?php
//brownuniversity.php
if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
    $_POST["name"];
}
?>

<form action="brownuniversity.php" method="post">
  If you want to take part in this star-gazing project, enter your name:
  <input type="text"  name="name">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Please explain your answer to OP

Comment: I copied and pasted your code on to Textpad and "ran" it on a browser. Unfortunately, I still get "Hello, Gavin, and welcome" at the top left of the web page. But thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Move the first five lines to the position you want it to appear at.